# How can i retrieve an index of records from the server into my Sencha Touch 2 app, and then retrieve a full model instance

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

It may be simple to set up a Sencha Touch 2 store to retrieve a handful of data to generate several model instances from a jsonp response. However, I am developing an app that works with a rather large data set (legal opinions) available on a server, so I have to retrieve a mere list of available records from the server--an index, if you will--and then retrieve a single full record when the user taps the item in a list.

I am looking for any recommended ways of doing this. Here is what I have set up so far, which is only partially working:

1. I have :index and :show RESTful actions defined on the server side to retrieve legal opinions.
2. On the client side, I have a model and a store for index entries (which comprise my list of available data), and they pull data via a jsonp response from the :index RESTful action on the server, to create an index of available data in a List component. The fields in these index entries do not contain the full text of legal opinions, but merely the names of the parties and a citation.
3. I have a model and store for full legal opinions. The store pulls a single legal opinion from the server at a time via the :show RESTful action on the server.
4. When the user taps one of the items in a list of legal opinions in the app, a listener fires an event, which a controller picks up. The controller uses the ID of the list item's corresponding record to determine the proper URL for the :show action on the server, like so:

   ```
       # Controller:
       onDisplayAuthority: function(list, record) {
         console.log('onDisplayAuthority');        
         this.activateAuthorityView(record);

         var authorityView = this.getAuthorityView();
         authorityStore = Ext.getStore('Authority');

         var authorityId = record.getData().id;
         var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/authorities/' + authorityId + '.json';
         var proxy = {
           type: 'jsonp',
           url: url,
           reader: {
               type: 'json',
               rootProperty: "authority"
           }
         };

         authorityStore.setProxy(proxy);
         authorityStore.load();

         authority = authorityStore.first();
         var data = authority.getData();

         authorityView.setRecord(authority);

         authorityView.getComponent("authorityViewBody").setData(data);
         authorityView.getComponent("titlebar").setTitle(data.title);

         Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(authorityView, this.slideLeftTransition);

     }
   ```

This code does not work. For some reason, if I run `console.log(authorityStore)` within the code, above, I can see that `authorityStore.data.all[0]` contains the full legal opinion. But, when I run `console.log(authorityStore.data.all[0])`, it returns `[]`. Furthermore, `authorityStore.first();` returns `undefined`, though the Sencha Touch 2 documentation shows that `#first()` is a method of a valid store, and `authorityStore` is a valid store.

So, either I am missing something basic, or I am just way off the beaten path on this.

Does anyone either (i) have a quick solution to my problem, or (ii) another method for using both :index: and :show actions to cut down on extraneous data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
onDisplayAuthority: function(list, record) {
    console.log('onDisplayAuthority');
    var authorityView = this.getAuthorityView();
    authorityStore = Ext.getStore('Authority');

    var authorityId = record.getData().id;
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/authorities/' + authorityId + '.json';
    var proxy = {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: url,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: "authority"
        }
    };

    authorityStore.setProxy(proxy);
    authorityStore.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            // the operation object contains all of the details of the load operation
            var data = records[0].getData();
            authorityView.setRecord(records[0]);

            authorityView.getComponent("authorityViewBody").setData(data);
            authorityView.getComponent("titlebar").setTitle(data.title);
        },
        scope: this});      

    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(authorityView, this.slideLeftTransition);
}
```

By placing the lines of code that set the data for `authorityView` within the callback from the #load method of the store, I was able to get access to the new record. I am not sure why I had to do it this way, and would appreciate comments. But, this approach *does* work.